# detect conflict time using query in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

This is my query.

```
("Select Count(*) From table1 where [t1] <= @TimeIn And [t2] >= @TimeOut;", cn)
```

My problem here is I can't compare other times. For example, if I input `7:00-9:00` then it will be saved as a new time and if I then input `8:00-10:00` it also save in my database how can I solve this I want to prevent the second input time from conflicting with the first?

Comment: Hi and welcome. I'm having a hard time understanding your question, could you try to clarify a bit what exactly the issue is and what you aim to do? Thanks

Comment: hello sir I want in my vb to conflict the time entry when it ia already in database with the time range but in my case i cannot do that.

Comment: @geno Can you add a bit more detail, such as a set of sample data in the table and sample values for the TimeIn and TimeOut parameters alongside what you expect the result to be, please?

Comment: @JayV.                                                                                 timein = 7:00.                                                                      timeout = 8:00.                                                                       its already in my database.                                            Then the next input                                                         timein = 7:30 timeout = 9:00.                                                it should not be save but in my case it can save.

Comment: I think you mean "compare" instead of "conflict", right? so you want to prevent inserting two rows with overlap?

Comment: yes sir thats what I meant sorry for that

Comment: Is there other way to solve this sir?

Comment: I've edited your question to match your comments. It is usually better to correct the info in the question itself instead of adding info in comments. If I didn't get things quite right, feel free to edit your question some more

Answer (score 1):

There are three combinations of checks you need to perform when looking for conflicting Time Windows.

1. Is the TimeIn within an existing entry (Time Window)
2. Is the TimeOut within an existing entry
3. Does the combination of TimeIn and TimeOut wholly cover an existing entry

This Sql should cover those options

```
select
    count(*) from table1 
where
    (
        @timeIn > [T1] AND @timeIn < [T2]
    ) -- TimeIn in existing window
    OR
    (
        @timeOut > [T1] AND @timeOut < [T2]
    ) -- TimeOut in existing window
    OR
    (
        @timeIn < [T1] AND @timeOut > [T2]
    ) -- TimeIn and TimeOut wholly covers existing window
```

If you get a 0 returned, there are no conflicts

Comment: there is a problem when I save 7:00-8:00 it can save but when I save 8:00-9:00 it says conflict.

Comment: @geno I changed the logic to not better handle the cases where In/Out times may be the same as an existing Time Window

Comment: I try it sir its ok but theres a little problem it can save thesame time like 7:00-8:00 it cant detect conflict but it can conflict the exceeding time which is ok but the problem it can save thesame time. Is there other way sir?

Comment: @geno Then, can you add more detail to your question to include sample data, sample input and what you expect to happen in each case please? Please add it to the question and not as a comment.