# how can I conflict days in my query using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

( "SELECT * FROM Table1 where Dday LIKE '%" & combo1.Text & "%' ;", cn)

The above is my query I got a problem while compairing the days in my scheduling because if I insert MF and I input other one like MWF it cant say conflict.

Comment: What database? What datatype? This isn't a vb.net problem or a visual studio problem. It is an SQL problem that depends on the dialect of sql that you need. Change your tags to reflect this.

Comment: Iam using ms access.

Comment: What datatype is Dday? Are you literally sending "MF" and "MWF"? To expand this, you insert Monday, Friday and want a conflict with Monday, Wednesday, Friday?

Comment: What is the difference between this question and your other two questions?  [conflicting time for schedule in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56503377/70104) and [detect conflict time using query in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56644537/70104)

Comment: I had that question before conflicting time but now problem is in days conflicting.